# hard link a Rel in the URL

Tags: html, css, url, rel

Is it possible to make a link such that it brings up the REL of a topic,

for example if a link is

```
<a href="picture.jpg" rel="lightbox">Click here</a>
```

Is it possible to have a user link so when they go to the page it automatically opens the lightbox?

For example http://example.com/?rel=lightbox&src=picture.jpg

or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but no browsers include a lightbox, so you'd need to write or find code to make one of those as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You may better use URLs like `http://domain.com/#lightbox`, and write a little script:

```
//jQuery sample
$(document).ready(function() { 
     if (location.hash == "#lightbox") {
          //Just show your lightbox manually
     }
});
```

Comment: having the href pointing to the actual image (or any other resource) to be displayed is preferable because use without javascript an still access the content. and if there is multiple link with a rel=lightbox you'll have to add some custom attribute to the link

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with a bit of jQuery

```
$(a[rel=lightbox]).click(function(e) {
  // open the lightbox with the link url inside
  return false
});
```